# Simulate scroll over element in WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a messenger-like web app opened in WebBrowser control. It has a contact list made with divs and js which I need to scroll down. It reacts to mouse scrolling when hovering but it also has a custom scroll bar. The page itself can't be scrolled, only div. The js code is a long obfuscated thing.

I need to either simulate scrolling or clicking at scrollbar bottom.

So how to do the scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
element.SetAttribute("scrollTop", "99999");
```